# Smartphone-specific words

Tags: перевод

How would one translate smartphone-specific words like:

- Back-Button
- Home-Button
- App-Menu
- App-Update

In a way that they are correctly understood in a smartphone-app context?

i.e. "The Back-Button has been deactivated. Please use the Home-Button to leave the App."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally, such buttons have the following names in Russian:

- `Назад`
- `Домой`
- `Главное меню`
- `Обновить приложение`

So, your example would be translated as follows: `Кнопка "Назад" не активна. Используйте кнопку "Домой", чтобы выйти из приложения.` It might be questionable, but I suppose "please" isn't obligatory in Russian when it comes to regular messages shown by an application.

Answer (score 1):

- Back-Button - *Кнопка "Назад" (or just "Назад")*
- Home-Button - *Кнопка "Домой"*
- App-Menu -  *Меню приложений*
- App-Update - *Обновление (or Обновление приложения)*

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't "Вперёд" mean something like "forward" or "next"?

Comment: @DevanLoper - Yes, it's not "Вперед" it should be "Домой".